respond with a custom file from query string or default if file doesn't exist
I have an nginx server running a react single page application, simple stuff:
server{
    server_name testing001.example.com;

    location / {
      root /var/www/testing001;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}

Inside my /var/www/testing001 directory, besides of the app files, i have a directory:
\runtimes
\runtimes\1.js
\runtimes\2.js
\runtimes\3.js
...
\runtimes\default.js

I want all the requests to https://testing.example.com/theRuntime.js?id={1,2,3,4} to:

serve me the respective file, depending on the id query string

this is working fine, using:



location ~* ^/theRuntime\.js {
        if ($arg_id != "") {
            set $id $arg_id;
            rewrite ^ /runtimes/$id.js last;
        }
    }


if the /runtimes/$id.js file doesn't exist, i want to serve /runtimes/default.js, or even just a common string directly from nginx i don't care

This is the part i can't figure out, i tried many combinations and it either stops serving me any file (404) or, in some cases, it defaults to the root index.html




See my answer here.
